# Installing Cloudera Hue on mac os x mountain lion

Tags: macos, twisted, cloudera, hue

So I've installed all the dependencies and when I do `make install`, the following error comes:

```
--- Installing core source structure...
--- Installing Desktop core...
INSTALL_DIR=/usr/local/hue make -C desktop install
INSTALL_DIR=/usr/local/hue/desktop/core \
        INSTALL_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/hue/desktop/conf \
        make -C core install-bdist
--- Building egg for Twisted
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing requirements to Twisted.egg-info/requires.txt
writing Twisted.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to Twisted.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to Twisted.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'Twisted.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'Twisted.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
conftest.c:1:10: fatal error: 'sys/epoll.h' file not found
#include <sys/epoll.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
building 'twisted.internet.cfsupport' extension
clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c twisted/internet/cfsupport/cfsupport.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/twisted/internet/cfsupport/cfsupport.o -w
twisted/internet/cfsupport/cfsupport.c:128:4: error: assignment to cast is illegal, lvalue casts are not supported
  ((PyObject*)__pyx_v_socket) = Py_None; Py_INCREF(((PyObject*)__pyx_v_socket));
  ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~
twisted/internet/cfsupport/cfsupport.c:134:4: error: assignment to cast is illegal, lvalue casts are not supported
  ((PyObject *)__pyx_v_socket) = __pyx_1;
  ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~
twisted/internet/cfsupport/cfsupport.c:829:4: error: assignment to cast is illegal, lvalue casts are not supported
  ((PyObject*)__pyx_v_obj) = Py_None; Py_INCREF(((PyObject*)__pyx_v_obj));
  ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~
twisted/internet/cfsupport/cfsupport.c:835:4: error: assignment to cast is illegal, lvalue casts are not supported
  ((PyObject *)__pyx_v_obj) = __pyx_1;
  ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~
4 errors generated.
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
make[2]: *** [/Users/rajat.khandelwal/Downloads/hue-2.4.0/desktop/core/build/Twisted/egg.stamp] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.recursive-install-bdist/core] Error 2
make: *** [install-desktop] Error 2
```

Also submitted the issue on github: https://github.com/cloudera/hue/issues/31

Answer (score 0):

You [need](https://github.com/cloudera/hue/issues/31) to delete
`desktop/core/ext-py/Twisted` and retry.

Also [Hue 2.5 release](http://gethue.tumblr.com/tagged/release) (which contains this fix) is around the corner (this Monday/Tuesday).